# Sql Like similar use in c++

Tags: c++

I would like to ask a simple question, is there any way to use "like" such thing in c++

LIKE '%s  I want some thing like this in c++ because if I want user to find something in the program, this simply matches all the related data.

Comment: There are regular expressions, but the syntax to using them is quite convoluted (when compared to the SQL `LIKE`).

Comment: Tell us more what do you want to do? Maybe it's better to connect your app to light db like SQLite?

Comment: I am making a simple c++ program using classes and objects on employee details, I am dynamically allocating memory according to user size, I am making find name function to implement this

Comment: This can actually be a pretty huge question. If you're storing employee details in a database, then how are you interacting with the db? Some kind of ORM? Can you just apply your filtering at the database level? And do you want to filter as you iterate, or create a new list containing only filtered objects?

Comment: if you are storing the "name" in a std::string, just use the "find" method and check if the return value is != -1

Comment: This may be of interest: https://github.com/hjiang/linqxx/wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) can be used to achieve what you want. There are two problems, though:

1.) They are really **complicated** to use compared to the simple SQL `LIKE` keyword.

2.) They are only a standard feature in **C++11**. If you write in "old" C++, then you'd have to use the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library.

However...

Looking at the **very basic `LIKE` examples** at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), you could in fact implement many of them in simple C++, using normal std::string functions.

For instance, let's have a look a this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%s';
```

This just means that for every string, you look at the last character and check if it's 's':

```
std::string s;
// ...
if (!s.empty() && (s[s.size() - 1] == 's') {
    // ...
}
```

Or this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country NOT LIKE '%land%';
```

In C++:

```
std::string s;
// ...
if (s.find("land") == std::string::npos) {
    // ...
}
```

So, in the end, it really depends on what exactly you'd want to do with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `boost's` [string algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) library, which can be used with `std::string`. It also gives you the option of using C++11 regular expressions. There are lots of functions for doing useful things (see the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp206817064)), such as `starts_with()` (or `istarts_with()` for case insensitive version)

Answer (score 1):

This is version copied from SQL Lite.

Now you can use: `patternCompare("A*A","AxA");`

```
//---------------------LIKE------------------------------
/*
** This lookup table is used to help decode the first byte of
** a multi-byte UTF8 character.
*/
static const unsigned char sqlite3Utf8Trans1[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
    0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00,
};



typedef  unsigned int u32;
typedef  unsigned char u8;

u32 sqlite3Utf8Read(
    const unsigned char **pz    /* Pointer to string from which to read char */
    ){
    unsigned int c;

    /* Same as READ_UTF8() above but without the zTerm parameter.
    ** For this routine, we assume the UTF8 string is always zero-terminated.
    */
    c = *((*pz)++);
    if (c >= 0xc0){
        c = sqlite3Utf8Trans1[c - 0xc0];
        while ((*(*pz) & 0xc0) == 0x80){
            c = (c << 6) + (0x3f & *((*pz)++));
        }
        if (c<0x80
            || (c & 0xFFFFF800) == 0xD800
            || (c & 0xFFFFFFFE) == 0xFFFE){
            c = 0xFFFD;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

/*
** Assuming zIn points to the first byte of a UTF-8 character,
** advance zIn to point to the first byte of the next UTF-8 character.
*/
#define SQLITE_SKIP_UTF8(zIn) {                        \
  if( (*(zIn++))>=0xc0 ){                              \
      while( (*zIn & 0xc0)==0x80 ){ zIn++; }             \
    }                                                    \
}


const unsigned char sqlite3UpperToLower[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
    36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,
    54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103,
    104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121,
    122, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107,
    108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125,
    126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143,
    144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161,
    162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179,
    180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197,
    198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215,
    216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233,
    234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251,
    252, 253, 254, 255
};


# define GlobUpperToLower(A)   if( !((A)&~0x7f) ){ A = sqlite3UpperToLower[A]; }


/*
** Compare two UTF-8 strings for equality where the first string can
** potentially be a "glob" expression.  Return true (1) if they
** are the same and false (0) if they are different.
**
** Globbing rules:
**
**      '*'       Matches any sequence of zero or more characters.
**
**      '?'       Matches exactly one character.
**
**     [...]      Matches one character from the enclosed list of
**                characters.
**
**     [^...]     Matches one character not in the enclosed list.
**
** With the [...] and [^...] matching, a ']' character can be included
** in the list by making it the first character after '[' or '^'.  A
** range of characters can be specified using '-'.  Example:
** "[a-z]" matches any single lower-case letter.  To match a '-', make
** it the last character in the list.
**
** This routine is usually quick, but can be N**2 in the worst case.
**
** Hints: to match '*' or '?', put them in "[]".  Like this:
**
**         abc[*]xyz        Matches "abc*xyz" only
*/
static int patternCompare(
    const u8 *zPattern,              /* The glob pattern */
    const u8 *zString
    )

{
    u32 c, c2;
    int invert;
    int seen;
    const u8 matchOne = '?';
    const u8 matchAll = '*';
    const u8 matchSet = '[';
    const u8 noCase =0;
    int prevEscape = 0;     /* True if the previous character was 'escape' */
    u32 esc = 0;

    //u32 esc;                         /* The escape character */

    while ((c = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern)) != 0){
        if (c == matchAll && !prevEscape){
            while ((c = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern)) == matchAll
                || c == matchOne){
                if (c == matchOne && sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString) == 0){
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            if (c == 0){
                return 1;
            }
            else if (c == esc){
                c = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
                if (c == 0){
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            else if (c == matchSet){
                //assert(esc == 0);         /* This is GLOB, not LIKE */
                //assert(matchSet<0x80);  /* '[' is a single-byte character */
                while (*zString && patternCompare(&zPattern[-1], zString) == 0){
                    SQLITE_SKIP_UTF8(zString);
                }
                return *zString != 0;
            }
            while ((c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString)) != 0){
                if (noCase){
                    GlobUpperToLower(c2);
                    GlobUpperToLower(c);
                    while (c2 != 0 && c2 != c){
                        c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString);
                        GlobUpperToLower(c2);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    while (c2 != 0 && c2 != c){
                        c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString);
                    }
                }
                if (c2 == 0) return 0;
                if (patternCompare(zPattern, zString)) return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else if (c == matchOne && !prevEscape){
            if (sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString) == 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (c == matchSet){
            u32 prior_c = 0;
            //assert(esc == 0);    /* This only occurs for GLOB, not LIKE */
            seen = 0;
            invert = 0;
            c = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString);
            if (c == 0) return 0;
            c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
            if (c2 == '^'){
                invert = 1;
                c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
            }
            if (c2 == ']'){
                if (c == ']') seen = 1;
                c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
            }
            while (c2 && c2 != ']'){
                if (c2 == '-' && zPattern[0] != ']' && zPattern[0] != 0 && prior_c>0){
                    c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
                    if (c >= prior_c && c <= c2) seen = 1;
                    prior_c = 0;
                }
                else{
                    if (c == c2){
                        seen = 1;
                    }
                    prior_c = c2;
                }
                c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zPattern);
            }
            if (c2 == 0 || (seen ^ invert) == 0){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (esc == c && !prevEscape){
            prevEscape = 1;
        }
        else{
            c2 = sqlite3Utf8Read(&zString);
            if (noCase){
                GlobUpperToLower(c);
                GlobUpperToLower(c2);
            }
            if (c != c2){
                return 0;
            }
            prevEscape = 0;
        }
    }
    return *zString == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/ has an example of what you want to do.  See lines 9-10 of the code near the bottom.